# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Composer Autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7.3

I'm getting this error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'TestApp\HelloWorld' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php-framework/index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php-framework/index.php on line 21

My guess is that composer.json is not connecting to the src folder, but not sure what's causing it. I'm using PHP 7.3.1

Here are my files:

index.php

```
declare(strict_types = 1);

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$helloWorld = new TestApp\HelloWorld();
$helloWorld->announce();
```

autoload.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInita3c559aaa188cb577ee6600701c362e7::getLoader();
```

HelloWorld.php

```
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace TestApp;

class HelloWorld
{
    public function announce(): void
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "philginsburg/php-framework",
    "description": "An example of a modern PHP application.",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "TestApp\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'TestApp\HelloWorld' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php-framework/index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php-framework/index.php on line 21

Comment: Where is your class file?

Comment: You don't have a `use` statement in your index file - you need to first import the namespace TestApp. Then you can invoke `new TestApp\HelloWorld();`

Answer (score 0):

Using your helloworld.php and composer.json, following should help you on your way:

project structure:

[image]

index.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

use TestApp\HelloWorld;

require dirname(__DIR__, 1) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
$helloWorld->announce();
```

output: Hello World!

Comment: I was still getting issues and it seems that the composer.json was cached. Using the command `composer dumpautoload` fixed the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should run command "composer update".